# Adding a format to the TextBox in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, maskedtextbox

I need to format an asp.net text box in such a way that it accepts the user input only in the form of

`### - ### - ###` **(#:numerics only)**.

Suggestions or answers please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[MaskedEdit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx) might be what you're looking for.

Here is an modified example from the link above:

```
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender runat="server"
    TargetControlID="TextBox2" 
    Mask="999-999-9999" />
```

Comment: Thanks it helped :) How to limit the user from entering only alphabets in the textbox using MaskedEditExtender?

Comment: If you wanted to change phone numbers `Mask="999-9999-9999"` to a say validating a U.S. state you would change it to `Mask="LL"` (2 alphabetic characters). Check out the link some more if you wanted to do more robust validation (e.g. A-C only).

Comment: to ensure user could add alphabets only, you should use `<asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="idName" runat="server" Enabled="True" 
            TargetControlID="txtBoxname" 
                    FilterType="Custom, UppercaseLetters, LowercaseLetters" 
                    ValidChars=""></asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>`
This code will ensure user could input alphabets only. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use jquery masked text box [Masked Input Plugin 1.2.2](http://digitalbush.com/2009/03/10/masked-input-plugin-122/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use MaskedEdit  ajax control..

MaskedEdit is an ASP.NET AJAX extender that attaches to a TextBox control to restrict the kind of text that can be entered. MaskedEdit applies a "mask" to the input that permits only certain types of characters/text to be entered. The supported data formats are: Number, Date, Time, and DateTime.

follow this link for details:
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can either use jQuery as suggested by DeveloperX or use the [MaskedEditExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx) from AjaxControlToolkit.